# Producing buttons with Direct2D and DirectWrite (C++, DirectX)

Tags: c++, button, directx, direct2d

I've been looking around for awhile about how to produce buttons using Direct2D and DirectWrite with no luck. I'm comfortable with shapes, text and that jazz. However, it suddenly occurred to me I might be looking about it in the wrong way.

Take the sentence:

> you draw your controls and content for your app using the Direct2D and
> DirectWrite APIs, handling all the input events directly.

I'm now thinking this means that instead of being able to quickly produce a fully functional button as I would using XAML. I would draw the button, manually check the location of the mouse on click, whether it's within the button boundaries and then handle the event? Similar method for hovering without the click.

Is this the kind of method required when using Direct2D and DirectWrite?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't any experience with DirectX, but in OpenGL I build my buttons from scratch. Assuming you have animated sprites implemented, your buttons are essentially sprites that play certain animations in response to being clicked, hovered over, etc., and which you can register callbacks with. In my 2D engine, I have a class called UiButton, which inherits Sprite, and listens for various UI events. It gets more complicated when you want to handle keyboard navigation (arrow keys + enter to select) as you have to think about how the buttons are connected and which of them has focus at any given moment.

Here is my implementation for reference:
Headers: https://github.com/RobJinman/dodge/tree/master/Dodge/include/dodge/ui
Source: https://github.com/RobJinman/dodge/tree/master/Dodge/src/ui

If you're not prepared to roll your own, Googling "direct2d gui framework" seems to bring up some promising results.

Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to draw a UI Button with Direct2D, you need to handle everything yourself, why? Direct2D is a 2D graphics API, not controls library. you need to draw the layout of your button, and handle the message of your button(such as click, mouse hover...), you lost lots of convenient and that's time-consuming, but the most important thing is: you can control it by yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Direct2D is a graphics library. UI controls like, Text-selection, Textbox, and Buttons is not a part of it. However the benefits of using Direct2D and DirectWrite is we can implement our own UI controls, and having a full control of it.

Please also see: `ID2D1Geometry::FillsContainsPoint()` for hit-testing task.